# I want to make a new dataframe from changes from old dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and i want to make a new dataframe containing features from the old dataframe.

Here is some dummy code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_msft = [['2020-1-1', 10, 11], ['2020-1-2', 15, 20], ['2020-1-3', 14, 12]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df_msft , columns = ['datetime', 'price_open', 'price_close'])

#Making a 'features' dataframe which will contain the features of the stocks in question
features = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.datetime).sort_index()

features['daily_change'] = df1.price_close/df1.price_open-1 # daily return
features['pct_change_on_day'] = df1.price_open/df1.price_close.shift(1)-1
```

When i do this my 'features' dataframe is filled with NaN values, does anyone know why this is?

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example where you have NaNs? Your code seems not to produce any

Comment: Odd, im running it on a jupyter notebook and running this code give me the NaN values for the features dataframe

Comment: have you changed anything? I tried again and I do have the NaNs,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `feature` and `df1` dataframes have different indexes. So when assigning, no alignment is found and your values are discarded.

You can overcome this by assigning the numpy array:

```
features['daily_change'] = (df1.price_close/df1.price_open-1).values # daily return
features['pct_change_on_day'] = (df1.price_open/df1.price_close.shift(1)-1).values
```

output:

```
          daily_change  pct_change_on_day
datetime                                 
2020-1-1      0.100000                NaN
2020-1-2      0.333333           0.363636
2020-1-3     -0.142857          -0.300000
```

or, better, make "datetime" the index of `df1`:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('datetime')
features['daily_change'] = (df1.price_close/df1.price_open-1) # daily return
features['pct_change_on_day'] = (df1.price_open/df1.price_close.shift(1)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
features.loc[:, 'daily_change'] = (df1.price_close/df1.price_open)-1
```

Comment: dataframe 'features' still has NaN values

Comment: Sorry, edited the answer.